# A function $f$ having a point of continuity relative to a subset $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I have been staring at the following question for sometime now and I feel as if the answer I have provided is almost too straight forward and alas, I am missing a deeper lesson.

> Let $(M,d_1)$ and $(N,d_2)$ be metric spaces with $A \subset M$. Show that if $f : (A,d_1) \to (N, d_2)$ is continuos at $a \in A$ if and only if, given $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ whenever $d_{1}(x,a) < \delta$ and $x \in A$.

---

**My Work**:

($\Rightarrow$)

Given that $f$ is continuous at $a \in A$, therefore $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta >0$ with $x \in A$ such that $d_{1}(x,a) < \delta$ $\implies d_{2}(f(x),f(a))< \epsilon$. So $d_{2}(f(x),f(a))< \epsilon$ whenever $d_{1}(x,a) < \delta$ and $x \in A$. $\blacksquare$

($\Leftarrow$)

Given that for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ whenever $d_{1}(x,a) < \delta$ and $x \in A$. So, by definition $f$ is continuous at $a \in A$. $\blacksquare$

As I stated in the introduction, I feel as if this was too easy and I was simply just abusing the defintion of continuity. Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: How exactly is continuity at a point defined in the course/book?

Comment: My professor defined continuity at a point $x \in M$ as the following: $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta >0$ (which depends on $\epsilon, x$ and $f$) such that $d_{M}(x,y) < \delta$  $\implies$ $d_{N}(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$ (where $(M, d_{M})$ and $(M, d_{N})$ respectively) @DanielFischer

Comment: Then you're not missing any deeper lesson here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, thats good to hear! Is there anything else I should add to my work?